# A word that entails the meaning of "the trait of being public"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, adjectives, abstract-nouns

I'm looking for a *descriptive* word to use when referring to *something that is public*.

It's better if I give an example:

Consider the adjective *red*. When something is *red* you could say it shows some *redness*.

The same thing with *public*, but I'm not sure if *publicness* is a word, and even if it is it just sounds weird.

Edit: Just found out that this class of words are called abstract nouns.

Comment: **Openness**? Are you looking for a word ends in -ness?

Comment: It does not necessarily has to end in -ness. I don't think openness conveys the same meaning, as something could be private but open. The meaning I'm looking for is something along "no one owns it".

Comment: "Sharedness" or "communality" are the best I can do; the former means having multiple owners but not necessarily being owned by all/nobody; the latter is in a few dictionaries but has multiple meanings (public spiritedness and public ownership).

Comment: You need to provide a sample sentence where the desired word would be used. This is required for single word requests. It helps us understand what specific meaning of public you want to convey and also indicates the register of the the communication.

Comment: It's not a sentence but the thing is I'm making a list of desirable properties for some thing, one of such would be 'publicness' or some synonym that entails the same meaning.

Comment: **Available for public**, **publicly**, **open for public**....? Still unclear what exactly do you mean by *the trait of being public*.

Comment: Can you provide a sentence where the word you want is missing, please?  I've a suspicion that '*public*' is the adjective you are looking for.

Comment: If '*public*' won't do, it's a shame '*publican*' isn't an adjective...

Comment: I am voting to close as there is no sentence given to demonstrate the context.

Answer (score 1):

'publicness' is a word. It sounds alright to me, too.

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/publicness

If something is not owned by anyone in particular, we say it is 'public property' or in 'public ownership'.

Comment: It sounds like an F# in the key of C. It looks like a striped shirt with plaid pants. It tastes like grilled onions on cake. It tastes like coffee when you're expecting tea. It feels like petting a cat with masking tape.

Comment: But it is probably better than other options.

Comment: Thank you! As I stated in the question, I personally believe that 'publicness' sounds a bit weird, and from what I've seen some dictionaries have it but some others don't. So if a good alternative comes up I'll use it. Otherwise, I'll just accept this answer in a few days.

Answer (score 1):

It rather depends on context but if the primary idea is of something not being private property, then **Commonality**

https://www.etymonline.com/word/commonality

commonality (n.)
c. 1300, "the people of a country, a community," from Old French comunalte, from comun (see common (adj.) as if from Medieval Latin *communalitas. A respelling of commonalty (late 13c.). Meaning "the common people" is attested from 1580s; that of **"state or quality of being shared"** is from 1954.

Comment: This would be greatly improved by including a dictionary definition supporting your usage.

Answer (score -1):

Even though it is used as an equivalent to press coverage these days, I think publicity is a word that suits your case.

> **Publicity**: the quality or state of being public

([source](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/publicity))

Comment: The OED says this meaning is *obsolete*. And it would indeed confuse everyone if you used it.

Comment: @PeterShor well Merriam-Webster has this as the first definition and it is almost to the word the same as the definition given in the title of the OP's question. If you hear the word on its own, this is not the first thing most people would think of, but in the right context, it could work!

Comment: But [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/publicity) doesn't even mention this definition.  And [American Heritage](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=publicity) calls it *archaic*. And the OED's last citation of it is from 150 ago.

Comment: I also thought of publicity but then it kind of lost its original meaning :D

Comment: @almosnow For posterity purposes, I thought I'd leave this answer here. It's a shame when we stop using words and never properly replace them with better alternatives. Also, publicness sounds almost equally weird to me.

Answer (score -2):

While you could go for *publicness*, it can sound a bit clumsy.

> **publicness** *noun*
> The quality, condition, or fact of being public
> [- lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/publicness)

You can try synonyms such as [exposure](https://www.lexico.com/definition/exposure), but it might sound better to turn the whole thing around and talk about [privacy](https://www.lexico.com/definition/privacy).

The following [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=how%20much%20publicness%2Chow%20much%20notoriety%2Chow%20much%20exposure%2Chow%20much%20privacy&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chow%20much%20notoriety%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chow%20much%20exposure%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chow%20much%20privacy%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Chow%20much%20notoriety%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chow%20much%20exposure%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chow%20much%20privacy%3B%2Cc0) plot suggests that both are more popular choices than *publicness*.

[image]